# Calculating chance behavior and behavioral strategies in delayed response paradigm

Tags: cognitive-modeling, working-memory, psychophysics

I am looking for more thoughts on appropriate ways of calculating chance behavior and subsequently calculating behavioral strategies for the following two types of tasks. Both have two types of errors - false alarms and missed responses (both of which occur in subjects performing the task).

1) delayed match to sample task in a go/no go paradigm - responding to match stimulus w/o an intervening  distractor or nonmatch stimulus (this is just to establish a baseline that responder and I are thinking along the same lines)

2) delayed match to sample task - responding to match stimulus with one or more intervening distractors or nonmatch stimuli. So subject has to withhold response and press to the match stimulus when it appears later in the trial.

This complexity can lead to subjects adopting different (sometimes idiosyncratic) strategies that may have varying demands on working memory. Some tasks make this easier by adopting a heuristic where match and nonmatch are from a different category, allowing the subject to match categories instead of actual sounds or movies, making the task significantly easier. I would like to be able to quantify or model this behavior and establish putative individual strategies.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci. What exactly is the task? Auditory? visual? A combination of both? Can you shortly describe a typical trial/run in a certain test?

Comment: Also you say: *...quantify or model this behavior* - what do you mean? Are you trying to get a handle on the number of false positives and false negatives?

Comment: separate conditions for auditory and visual, using complex naturalistic stimuli for both (sounds like human sounds and musical instruments, and movies for the same)